# how to fix interrupted Ubuntu 16.04 update process?

Tags: 16.04, apt, dpkg, update-manager

I started a normal software update process which was recommended in ubuntu last night and stupidly forgot to plug in the charger for my notebook... So at some point in time laptop shutdown but I could start the laptop again today, but I can't install any programs anymore. The output for `sudo dpkg-configure -a` is at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/NhPc2gk2). Could some guide me through this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @user535733 I think those errors about missing confugrations are due to an aborted installation - so probably the update was installing some software like texlive ect. when the shutdown happend. But I can't figure out which package I have to reinstall. I tried to purge perl, but then apt wanted to remove alot of other packages, which is why I didn't executed the purge in the end. Currently I am trying to purge texlive and then try to reinstall it.  I thought maybe you could somehow find out which package is missing?

Comment: @user535733 thanks! I did not understand the log messages, but now I see why you were blaming gnuplot... Well after the commands ´sudo apt-get purge gnuplot´ and ´sudo apt-get autoremove´ everything works again. Thank you very much!